# Python regex performance: Best way to iterate over texts with thousands of regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I researched a lot but did not find anything that really helped me. Maybe my approach is just weird - maybe someone can get my thoughts in the right direction.

So here is the situation:

I need to process large amounts of texts (hundreds of thousand). In those texts I need to find and process certain strings:

1. Certain “static” substrings (like case numbers), that I pull from my database (also hundreds of thousand)
2. Strings that I match with a regex that is built dynamically to match every possible occurrence – where the last part of the regex will be set dynamically

So as becomes clear, this results in a stupid amount of iterations, because every text needs to be fed in a function that runs it through hundreds of thousand regexes – and after all will lead to really long runtimes.

Is there a better and faster way to accomplish the desired task? The way it is done now works but is painfully slow and puts heavy load on the server for weeks.

Some example code to illustrate my thoughts:

```
import re

cases = []          # 100 000 case numbers from db
suffixes = []       #  500 diffrent suffixes to try from db

texts = []          # 100 000 for the beginning - will become less after initial run

def process_item(text: str) -> str:
    for s in suffixes:
        pattern = '(...)(.*?)(%s|...)' % s
        x = re.findall(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)
        for match in x:
            # process the matches, where I need to know which suffix matched
            pass
    for c in cases:
        escaped = re.escape(c)
        x = re.findall(escaped, text, re.IGNORECASE)
        for match in x:
            # process the matches, where I need to know which number matched
            pass

    return text


for text in texts:
    processed = process_item(text)
```

Every idea is highly appreciated!

Comment: You said you pull them from a database.. can you not make a suffix field?

Comment: @Sayse not sure if I got you right: I´m pulling the data from django model, the model has a field with the suffix. I am iterating over them and put them in the regex pattern with the % s

Comment: Ah i misunderstood.. essentially the idea is to rather than to look at how to do this, work out why there is so many variables to begin with and look at reducing those

Comment: @Sayse Thanks! I thought about that. However I could not think of a way to reduce them, since I will never know where the variables could accure and where not. So every text could possibly match to any of the generated regexes -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment, but just some thoughts:

From what you've posted it looks like that the stuff you want to search for are always the same, so why don't just join them in big regexp and compile that big regexp before running the loop.

This way you do not compile the regular expression for every iteration, but just once.

e.g.

```
import re

cases = []          # 100 000 case numbers from db
suffixes = []       #  500 diffrent suffixes to try from db

texts = []          # 100 000 for the beginning - will become less after initial run

bre1 = re.compile('|'.join(suffixes), re.IGNORECASE)
bre2 = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(c) for c in cases]), re.IGNORECASE)

def process_item(text: str) -> str:
    x = re.findall(bre1, text)
    for match in x:
        # process the matches, where I need to know which suffix matched
        pass

   x = re.findall(bre1, text)
   for match in x:
       # process the matches, where I need to know which number matched
       pass

    return text


for text in texts:
    processed = process_item(text)
```

If you could reliably find the `case number` in the `text` (e.g. if it has some identifier before it) it would be better to find the case number using `re.search` and have the case numbers in `set` and test for membership in that set.

e.g.

```
cases = ["123", "234"]
cases_set = set(cases)

texts = ["id:123", "id:548"]

sre = re.compile(r'(?<=id:)\d{3}')
for t in texts:
    m = re.search(sre, t)
    if m and m.group() in cases_set:
        # do stuff ....
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I will try your approch this evening. I just as well thought about how to write a regex (or multiple) that could find every casenumber in the text, to then look if it exists in my list with case numbers. This should be way faster right? btw its a shame that new contributors cant comment...

Comment: Yes, if you could write regexp catching your `case number` then it would be faster. But convert that `list` to `set` as `set`s are much better for membership testing.
Also if the `case number`s are "numbers" then it might be better to convert them to `int` (saves memory).

Comment: Glad you can comment now! :) These are some pretty helpfull tips, thanks! The numbers are alpha numerical, so I will try the "set". For me as a hobby-coder it is new to deal with such vast amounts of data, so every optimization tip is really helpful.

Comment: Regarding: _its a shame that new contributors cant comment..._ – In this case, it was a blessing - otherwise we perhaps wouldn't have this perfectly acceptable answer. In my opinion, it's often a shame that contributers, however new or old, write comments which could as well serve as answers.